# Do JSP support runtime string substitution for resource bundle text?

Tags: java, jsp, resourcebundle

In the resource bundle properties file I have following text

`system.invalidID = This accountID $ is not valid for current session.`

I want to replace dynamically $(this will be the actual ID at runtime) from the above resource text in my JSP and java Class.

Can we do this in JSP and java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually create a simple class with a method something like

```
public class ResourceBundleHelper{

    public String resolveMessage(String key){
     //code
    }

}
```

and then create instance of this class and put it to `ServletContext` and then from jsp el

```
${resourceBundleHelper.resolveMessage(YOUR_VARIABLE)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can parameterize messages using JSTL's `<fmt:message>` and `<fmt:param>` tags together.

The `basename` attribute below refers to the base name of your `ResourceBundle` property files, which must be accessible on the webapp's classpath. Putting everything together looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.y.app.Messages" var="bundle" />
<fmt:message bundle="${bundle}" key="system.invalidID">
  <fmt:param value="${attemptedID}" />
</fmt:message>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `JSTL Core <fmt:bundle> Tag`

see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_bundle_tag.htm